I have a Python file that I want to run in an HTML file when a button is pressed using PyScript. How would I do this?
I have a Python file called main.py, which I want to run when a button is pressed in a website I am creating, but I'm unsure how to go about this. I have looked at several different examples on the PyScript website but nothing seems to be what I want. Is it possible and if so how would I do it?
HTML code:
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  
<head> 
    <title>Secure Login</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
          href="style.css"> 
    <link rel=”stylesheet” href=”htpps://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css” />
  <script defer 
  src=”htpps://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js”>
  </script>
</head> 
  
<body> 
    <div class="main"> 
        <h1>Secure Login</h1> 
        <h3>Enter your login credentials</h3> 
        <p>Not registered?  
              <a href="#" 
               style="text-decoration: none;"> 
                Create an account 
            </a> 
        </p> 
    </div> 
</body> 
  
</html>
<script>
  function runpython() {
      <py-script src=”/my_own_file.py”>
      </py-script>
  }
</script> 
<button onclick="runpython()">please work</button>


The tutorial https://pyscript.github.io/docs/2024.4.1/beginning-pyscript/ shows how to call a Python function when a button is pressed.

(You're using quite an old version of PyScript - alpha is two years old at time of writing! The following is written using the most recent release, 2024.4.1.)
Typically, you'd have a function within a file be executed when you trigger an event, using either pyscript.when or inline event handlers.
If you really need to execute a whole file, I think the closest would be something like:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/releases/2024.4.1/core.css">
<script type="module" src="https://pyscript.net/releases/2024.4.1/core.js"></script>

<button id="run">Run main.py</button>

<py-config>
    [files]
    "main.py" = "main.py"
</py-config>

<script type="py">
    from pyscript import when

    @when('click', '#run')
    def run_main(evt):
        with open("main.py") as f:
            exec(f.read())
</script>

